# Transparent proxy that supports TLS-PSK

Tags: proxy, iot, transparentproxy, tls-psk

I'm trying to research a device that uses TLS-PSK as its cipher suite for server authentication. However, mitmproxy nor Burp Suite support the TLS-PSK ciphers. For Burp, this is the underlying Java/BouncyCastle implementation that does not support it.

Can anyone recommend an option to proxy traffic from a device that utilizes TLS-PSK?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a recommendation of a proxy that supports TLS-PSK? If so, stunnel supports this : https://www.stunnel.org/auth.html